# How to retrieve a cluster of connected users from table of connections between two users? in Python

Tags: python

The table consists of pairs of users which are connected together. The following is a hypothetical example:

user1, user2

a, b
a, c
e, a
c, e
d, e
a, e
j, e
j, d
f, e
j, f
f, d

How can I make clusters or a dictionary which says which userscouples or duo's has other user duo's in common: (wanted hypothetical result is:)

c1: a, b
c2: a, c, e
c3: d, e, f, j

Does anyone know how to form a query statement or create an algorithm to retrieve the connections cluster in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems this would be connected components for a graph i.e. [Connected Components in an undirected graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/)

Comment: Hi DarylG how can I let the function do this for the dataframe where my couples are in?

Comment: @Joan--Can you provide a [minial representative example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Would be helpful to show 1) data for generating a dataframe and 2) desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example of what i have now, the problem here is that as well al the couples apear and also these couples apear that are in a trio or quatro what isn't right

```
 lijst = []
    verzameling = set()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if verzameling == set():
            verzameling.add(row['city1'])
            verzameling.add(row['city2'])
        else:
            if row['city1'] in verzameling or row['city2'] in verzameling:
                verzameling.add(row['city1'])
                verzameling.add(row['city2'])
    
            else:
                lijst.append(verzameling)
                verzameling = {row['city1']}
                verzameling.add(row['city2'])
    print(lijst)
```

the picture below is an example of how the file looks now, it's a csv-file that i load in as a dataframe in python
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1P6U.png)
i want to group all cities so that every city in the group has every other city in common

Comment: @joan--this should be added to your question since it clarifies your question.  Also, StackOverflow prefers text over images of data to make it easy for others to use your data.